# How to use selenium to call angular function (ng-click)

Tags: python, angular, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

I am trying to call a angular ng-click using selenium. This question is based on this javascript:

```
<span class="col" ng-click="getHope(1,'pray','smile')">100%</span>
```

This I turned into:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[ng-click=getHope(1,'pray','smile')]").click()
```

I even tried adding span:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[ng-click=getHope(1,'pray','smile')]").click()
```

and adding :

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span[ng-click=getHope(1,\'pray\',\'smile\')]").click()
```

But I can the following error:

```
 selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: 
 Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
```

I tried to mimic [this link](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/28308/locating-ng-click-in-protractor), but it does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following XPath selector:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@ng-click=\"getHope(1,'pray','smile')\"]").click()
```

But a better solution (IMO) would be to execute the function `getHope` with a JS executor directly.

Answer (score 3):

As per the HTML you have shared to `click()` on the desired element you can use either of the following *Locator Strategies* :

- `xpath` :

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='col' and contains(.,'100%')]").click()
  ```
- `xpath` :

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='col' and starts-with(@ng-click,'getHope') and contains(.,'100%')]").click()
  ```
- `css_selector` :

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.col[ng-click^='getHope']").click()
  ```

Comment: That actually worked, but there are more spans that contain '100%'. This only selects the first one. Sorry, I should've mentioned it.

Comment: @nappingkid Added more options, check if any of those suffices to your needs. Let me know the status.

Comment: It is a bit more complicated than that I see. These solutions only select the first span.
There are two identical divs that contain these span with 100%. The only differrence of the divs is that they contain <div ng-click="hideerror({target:'#heavenQuanity'},'heaven')"><span ...>100%</span></div> the other contains <div ng-click="hideerror({target:'#hellQuanity'},'hell')"><span ...>100%</span></div> Could I use this info to specify the selection even more?

Comment: Checkout the _second_ and _third_ option in my answer.

Comment: Tried both, but they still select only the first span alone. I realize that this website is not wel designed for a scraper.